# Application is breaking in IE 11 with Enterprise Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery to create my client side code , it works fine with Chrome, Mozilla,Edge with when it comes to IE it breaks and I notice it is by default loading on Enterprise Mode and when I disable Enterprise Mode from settings, it works fine. I have few thousands of users who use IE and helping them or asking them to change the settings isn't possible.

I saw a question about IE enterprise mode but it was mostly on configuration which doesn't suit for all, I request if there is any code fix needs to be done to solve this please help me . Thank you.

Comment: what is the error? which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jquery datatables1.10.2, error is ,the web page is broken on IE 11 with Enterprise Mode , disabling Enterprise Mode it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Into your header

or make sure your doctype is

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: Tried adding the tag but no luck..!